# Different Instance of Fragment inside an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

We are going to write an app, in one section of app user enter to an `Activity` that call it `PostDetailsActivity`.

In this Activity we have a fragment call it `PostDetailsFragment`. We apply an `Interface` to communicate between this fragment and activity

```
public interface changeFragment{
    void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String backStack);
}
```

In `PostDetailsFragment` we have post and it's related posts. related post listed in recyclerview bu an adapter. when user click on Item in adapter, adaoter act like this:

```
PostDetailsFragment fragment = PostDetailsFragment.newInstance(GsonString);
mListener.replaceFragment(fragment, fragment.getFragmentKey());
```

and in Activity we act like this:

```
@Override
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String backstackName) {

    if(fragment instanceof PostDetailsFragment){
        fragmentPostDetails = (PostDetailsFragment) fragment;
    }

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backstackName);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

}
```

**What we doing**: we create one Activity and if user click on related posts, activity just replace fragment with new instance of PostDetailsFragment with new data.

**Issue**: after five or more and less, App crashed and got `OoutOfMemory` Error!

I attache MAT too
[image: figure 1]
[image]

**How we should manage this problem?**

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons inside your fragment itself. Are you dealing with bitmaps or media?

Comment: Try to temporary disable some parts of your fragment (say if you are using picture gallery - remove it). Switch fragments, look at memory monitor and you can easily find where is you leak

Comment: @Leo  Yep, post are like pinterest app, and focus on image, main post and it's related post, all of them contain image. How can release resources when fragments get replace?

Comment: So the problem is probably because of your Bitmaps. Maybe their size is too large. If you use a lot of bitmaps then try to use week references. Google for something like "Bitmap OutOfMemory" and you will find useful stuff. You can not fix this problem just by switching your fragments in a different way. You rather have to find the leak and fix it